# Set up Nuget server at home

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, nuget-package

Just a quick question.

I have Visual Studio 2010 professional edition installed at my home desktop. Can I set up Nuget server for practice or self learning?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly can: [Hosting Your Own NuGet Feeds](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the free [MyGet.org](http://www.myget.org) service and focus on creating the packages and learning the commands instead.

No need to set up your own NuGet server (unless you want to learn how to set it up). MyGet is an ideal solution to jump-start your NuGet learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing stopping you from installing the server, but the fact that you are not running the most recent version of Visual Studio.

You can install and use NuGet from thier website, just download a previous version of the software.